# Is the RAM page size always the same of swap disk page size?

Tags: memory, paging

Could they be different in some case? How is RAM page size determined/changed?

Comment: No  However more info on a specific OS and the issue you are trying to solve would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  The processor page size equalling the page/swap file/volume unit size is common, for starters because it's the case for Windows NT on IA32 processors, but far from a universal given.

BSD 4.1 on VAXen, for example, pages to disc in units of *clusters*.  The hardware page size is 512 bytes.  A *cluster* is usually 1024 bytes, twice the page size.  (In fact, it tries to be clever about pre-fetching extra pages for a page-in.  So one or more clusters are paged in in groups called *klusters*.)

It's not the page size that changes.  You have completely the wrong end of the stick there.  The page size is fixed by the processor architecture.  Processor architectures can support *more than one possible size* for a page.  But those sizes are fixed.

It's the *cluster* size that can change.  That's decided in software.  One could in theory decide to rewrite BSD 4.x to operate in terms of 4KiB clusters on a VAX, for example.  Again, though, because processor page sizes of 4KiB and larger are common nowadays, this idea is very rare.

### Further reading

- Samuel J. Leffler, Marshall Kirk McKusick, Michael J. Karels, and John S. Quarterman (1988).  "§ 5.2 Evoluation of 4.3BSD Memory Management".   *The design and implementation of the 4.3BSD operating system*.  Addison-Wesley. ISBN 0201061961.